# Select and Update a value in an XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Options>
  <Gestion>
    <Prêts>
      <NbrRenouvlement>5</NbrRenouvlement>
      <DureeEmprunt>10</DureeEmprunt>
      <NbrEmprunt>3</NbrEmprunt>
    </Prêts>
    <Réservations>
      <NbrReservation>3</NbrReservation>
      <DureeReservation>7</DureeReservation>
    </Réservations>
  </Gestion>
  <Config>
    <RememberMe>False</RememberMe>
    <ConnexionAutomatique>False</ConnexionAutomatique>
    <ShowToolTip>True</ShowToolTip>
  </Config>
</Options>
```

I want to select the value of NbrRenouvlement which is 5, and this is the code I wrote:

```
String nbrReservation = String.Empty;
var makeInfo = from reservations in doc.Descendants("Réservations") 
           select reservations.Element("NbrReservation").Value;
```

but this code is returns a Generic List, inspite of the value I want to select is just one number so I need to work with a foreach loop:

```
foreach (string s in makeInfo.Distinct()) 
               nbrReservation.Text += s;
```

This methods works fine but it's too long for select one value, is there any other method that allows me to select the value of NbrReservation from that XML file?

And how can I change this value ?

Comment: You want to get the value of `NbrRenouvlement` but your code tries to get the value of `Réservations/NbrReservation`. Can you clarify what  you really want to do?

Comment: I want to get the value as a string not as an IEnumerable<String>

Comment: Su Sha, What you want to get(`NbrRenouvlement`) and your code is doing contradicts(you are selecting `Réservations/NbrReservation`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I want to select the value of NbrRenouvlement*

You can use XPath (System.Xml.XPath).

```
var five = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//NbrRenouvlement").Value;
```

And this is the code similar to the one in your question

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var makeInfo = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Réservations/NbrReservation");
if (makeInfo != null)
{
    var val = makeInfo.Value;
    //makeInfo.Value = newValue;
}
```

Comment: I have a question about this: XDocument.Parse(xml); am I should change the parametre xml by the path of my xml file or by XDocument.Load(filePath)

Comment: `Parse` is used to load the xml from a string variable. If you load the xml from a file, use `Load`

Comment: I tried this code but it didn't worked it returns an empty string

Comment: @SuSha What did you try? Since i tested it before posting and it works. Please post your code.

Comment: Sorry it's my false I missed a casting

Answer (score 1):

Reading and saving value:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var nbrReservation = xdoc.Descendants("Réservations")
                         .Single() // if you have single reservations node
                         .Element("NbrReservation");
int value = (int)nbrReservation;
nbrReservation.SetValue(42);
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

Comment: The value of NbrRenouvlement can be changed

Comment: @SuSha then why you are asking to get value of NbrRenouvlement which is 5? (see my quote at the top of answer)

Comment: because in the example I gave the the value of NbrRenouvlement is 5 but this valu can be changed

Comment: @SuSha so you want to get this node by name, not by value?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of string (`IEnumerable<string>`):

```
var makeInfo = from reservations in doc.Descendants("Réservations") 
       select reservations.Element("NbrReservation").Value;
```

If you rephrase it as:

```
var makeInfo = (from reservations in doc.Descendants("Réservations") 
       select reservations.Element("NbrReservation")).First().Value;
```

Then you can do this:

```
nbrReservation.Text += s;
```

This is assuming that `NbrReservation` node is guaranteed to be in the XML.